# Why is it so much slower to export my data to .xlsx than to .xls or .csv?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a dataframe that I'm exporting to Excel, and people want it in .xlsx. I use `to_excel`, but when I change the extension from .xls to .xlsx, the exporting step takes about 9 seconds as opposed to 1 second. Exporting to a .csv is even faster, which I believe is due to the fact that it's just a specially formatted text file.

Perhaps the .xlsx files just added a lot more features so it takes longer to write to them, but I'm hoping there is something I can do to prevent this.

Comment: `.xlsx` files are bundles of files that have been compressed into a `zip` archive. The latter is probably a not insignificant cause.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pandas defaults to using OpenPyXL for writing xlsx files which can be slower than than the xlwt module used for writing xls files.

Try it instead with [XlsxWriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org) as the xlsx output engine:

```
df.to_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', engine='xlsxwriter')
```

It should be as fast as the xls engine.

Comment: It worked! Thank you. It ran in 3.1 seconds, of which the export was about 1.5 seconds.

Also, for anyone reading this, make sure you have pandas version 0.13.1 because it didn't work for me on 0.12.0.

Comment: The problem is, you cannot append new sheets with this engine I guess...

Comment: @MehmedB This question, and the answer, is old.These days OpenPyXL is as fast as XlsxWriter so you can use it OpenPyXL you need to add sheets.

Answer (score 3):

As per different Python to Excel modules benchmark, pyexcelerate has better performance.
Below code used to take sqlite tables data into xlsx file datasheets. table is not stored in xlsx file unless raw size is less than 1000000 raws. In that case info is stored in csv file.

```
def passfile(datb, tables):
    """copy to xlsx or csv files tables from query results"""
    import sqlite3
    import pandas as pd
    import timeit
    import csv
    from pyexcelerate import Workbook
    from pathlib import Path
    from datetime import date
    dat_dir = Path("C:/XML")
    db_path = dat_dir / datb
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)                # database connection
    c = conn.cursor()
    today = date.today()
    tablist = []
    with open(tables, 'r') as csv_file:             # tables to be collected file
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        for line in csv_reader:
            tablist.append(line['table'])           #column header
    xls_file = "Param" + today.strftime("%y%m%d") + ".xlsx"
    xls_path = dat_dir / xls_file                   # xls file path-name
    csv_path = dat_dir / "csv"                      # csv path to store big data
    wb = Workbook()                                 # excelerator file init
    for line in tablist:
        try:
            df = pd.read_sql_query("select * from " + line + ";", conn)  # pandas dataframe from sqlite
            if len(df) > 1000000:                   # excel not supported
                print('save to csv')
                csv_loc = line + today.strftime("%y%m%d") + '.csv.gz'   # compressed csv file name
                df.to_csv(csv_path / csv_loc, compression='gzip')
            else:
                data = [df.columns.tolist()] + df.values.tolist()
                data = [[index] + row for index, row in zip(df.index, data)]
                wb.new_sheet(line, data=data)
        except sqlite3.Error as error:  # sqlite error handling
            print('SQLite error: %s' % (' '.join(error.args)))
    print("saving workbook")
    wb.save(xls_path)
    end_time = timeit.default_timer()
    delta = round(end_time - start_time, 2)
    print("Took " + str(delta) + " secs")
    c.close()
    conn.close()


passfile("20200522_sqlite.db", "tablesSQL.csv")
```