# Write.xlsx Is Running Very Slow, Can I Speed It Up?

Tags: r, package, rstudio

I've been using Write.xlsx to export my results into each tab of an Excel workbook and it's working just as I'd like it to be, except it's running exceptionally slow. It took me 9 and a half hours to run about 120 lines of write.xlsx. Here is the code I'm using, with "Fruit" as an example:

```
forecast_custom <- function(selected_fruit) {
  df_sub <- subset(FruitData, Fruit == selected_fruit)
  ts_sub <- ts(df_sub$avg)
  forecast(auto.arima(ts_sub), h = 12)
}
```

Then:

```
ForecastApple <-  forecast_custom("Apple")
ForecastBanana <-  forecast_custom("Banana")
```

Finally:

```
write.xlsx2(ForecastApple, file="ForecastModel.xlsx", sheetName="Apple", 
row.names=FALSE)
write.xlsx2(ForecastBanana, file="ForecastModel.xlsx", sheetName="Banana", 
append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
```

And lets say these forecasts and write.xlsx (I switched from write.xlsx to write.xlsx2 and it's still slow) go on for 100 lines. Any reason why it would be running so slow?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `fwrite()` from the `data.table` package. The output is .csv but it is super fast!

Comment: There are alternative R packages (not to mention Python) includiong: writexl, XLConnect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```py
filename='ForecastModel.xlsx`
if os.path.exists(filename):          # engine=xlsxwriter only support WRITE no matter mode='a' OR mode='w'
    with pd.ExcelWriter(filename, mode='a') as writer:
        ForecastApple.to_excel(writer, engine='xlsxwriter', sheet_name='Apple', encoding='utf8', index=False)
        ForecastBanana.to_excel(writer, engine='xlsxwriter', sheet_name='Banana', encoding='utf8', index=False)
else:                                 # creating "ForecastModel.xlsx" if not.
    with pd.ExcelWriter(filename, mode='w+') as writer:
        ForecastApple.to_excel(writer, engine='xlsxwriter', sheet_name='Apple', encoding='utf8', index=False)
        ForecastBanana.to_excel(writer, engine='xlsxwriter', sheet_name='Banana', encoding='utf8', index=False)
```

According to jmcnamara in the answer of [Why is it so much slower to export my data to .xlsx than to .xls or .csv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23094980/why-is-it-so-much-slower-to-export-my-data-to-xlsx-than-to-xls-or-csv):

> Pandas defaults to using OpenPyXL for writing xlsx files which can be slower than than the xlwt module used for writing xls files.
>
> Try it instead with XlsxWriter as the xlsx output engine.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, as well as some annoying errors using `write.xlsx()`. `write_xlsx()` from the `writexl` package works great and is way faster! And it works fine with tibbles.

For more info see https://ropensci.org/technotes/2017/09/08/writexl-release/

Answer (score 0):

You could try `write_csv()` from the `readr` package (although as the same suggests you will be creating a number of csv files instead of a single workbook). It's very fast, about twice as fast as `write.csv`.